# JSON with XMLHttpRequest and questions about memory usage

Tags: javascript, json, memory, memory-management

I am loading JSON file with XMLHttpRequest. I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I only found this one.

The file is huge, it contains many game maps that are in two-dimentional arrays 50x50 each. I want memory to contain only the neccessary data at a time, load additional data when needed, and eventually clear the data not used anymore, if it gets too big.

I have very little understanding, when it comes to anything that has to do with memory. If I load a big JSON, does it stay in memory? Will it be better to split JSON into smaller files and load only needed part at a time? Is this possible? When is JSON cleared from memory? Do I need to do it manually? Are many XMLHttpRequests also a bad thing? Maybe different, faster method?

I just want a huge JSON to work well on mobile devices.

Thanks